# How to specify location of file with wget download?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I try to download file so `wget -P /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/movies/2019/ -O love.mp4 https://example.com/video.mp4`

But it locates the file in `root` and not in `/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/movies/2019/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the directory while using the '-O' parameter:

```
wget -O /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/movies/2019/love.mp4 https://example.com/video.mp4
```